# C# CellValueNeeded blocks Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class inherited for Form. This class contains, among other things, a Button and a custom DataGridView.

The DataGridView displays item depending on a DataBase and it can take a long time to load. I actualy have :

```
public partial class dlgDetailsObj : Form
{
    List<object> listItem;
    public dlgDetailsObj(List<object> obj)
    {
        listItem = obj;
        customGridView.CellValueNeeded += onCellValueNeeded;
        customGridView.VirtualMode = true;
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);

        customGridView.RowCount = listItem.Count; // When RowCount changes, items are loaded
    }

    private void onCellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= listItem.Count)
            return;

        String value = "";
        customItem item = listItem[e.RowIndex];
        if (e.ColumnIndex == columnId.Index)
        {
            value = item.Name; // If Name is null, it is loaded from dataBase (can take time)
        }
        /* Some else if*/

        e.Value = value;
}
```

My problem is that when the customGridView starts to load, the close button is not loaded and user can't click on it (to cancel if loading is too long).

How can I put my piece of code to be sure user can cancel ?

Edit :
I'm using virtual GridView (I updated my code)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988458(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that both the UI and the data loading is happening sequentially in the same thread.

So the UI is blocked until all the data is processed. You should try using multithreading and load the data in a separate thread than the UI.

Something like this

```
public partial class dlgDetailsObj : Form
{
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);

        UpdateListFromDatabase();
    }

    private static void UpdateListFromDatabase()
    {
         var thread = new Thread(() =>
             {
                 //code that should run separately from the UI
             });
         thread.Start();
    }       
}
```

Here's a link that will help you with the basics.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2010/11/18/Multithreading-in-WinForms.aspx

Comment: I edited my question i'm using VirtualMode and I have not achieved to adapt your example to my code

Comment: Where is the data being loaded from?